# Hide the loading bar for specific page

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar

I am using the [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar), And I have included it as below to angular module. 
`angular.module('myApp', [
        'chieffancypants.loadingBar'])`

I want to disable/hide the loading bar when i load the login page. 
**localhost:3000/login** 
and for rest of the pages it should be enabled.

After going to the document still I am unable to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a module for each page, and a finite set of pages? You could add the loadingBar as a dependency to all of the individual page modules *except* the login page.

Comment: There are many pages so adding to each is cumbersome. So I thought of adding dependency to only login page and set that loading to complete like this. :  cfpLoadingBar.complete(); on $scope.init. But it dint work..

Answer (score 3):

I was in same issue. I resolved declaring a global variable to control if the loading bar should be shown.

In `loading-bar.js", after declare the interceptor :

```
 var interceptor = ['$q', '$cacheFactory', '$timeout', '$rootScope', '$log', 'cfpLoadingBar', function ($q, $cacheFactory, $timeout, $rootScope, $log, cfpLoadingBar) {
     $rootScope.showLoading = true;
```

and in request block:

```
if (!config.ignoreLoadingBar && !isCached(config) && $rootScope.showLoading)
```

I've used the `$rootScope` to turn the variable accesible globally
Then, before the request I don't want to show the loading, I set this:

```
$rootScope.showLoading = false;
```

And set it again to `true` after the request, this did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I cannot test it as I am not working on it anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

My workaround was to add `ignoreLoadingBar: true` to the `$http` request in my controller. 
I then manually triggered the loading bar `cfpLoadingBar.start()` and manually stopped it when I was finished loading images
`cfpLoadingBar.complete()`

```
cfpLoadingBar.start()
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: window.location.origin + '/api/photos/main',
        ignoreLoadingBar: true
    }).then( fucntion(bla){
      /// Do some stuff
      cfpLoadingBar.complete()
})
```